# syslog-ng error when I try to configure log for facility LOG_LOCAL1

Tags: php, linux, logging, syslog, syslog-ng

I"m in a CentosOS linux environment and I'm using syslog-ng to configure my logging for my php app.

on the php side I generate logs using the code below:

```
openlog(‘Program1', LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL1);
syslog(LOG_INFO, "My log message");
closelog();
```

Before I edited my syslog-ng.conf file all of the logs generated from the php code were logged into /var/log/messages.

I want to save my log to /var/log/program1.log so I added the following line to syslog-ng.conf:

```
local1.info /var/log/program1.log
```

But when I restarted the syslog-ng service I"m getting the following error:

```
Stopping syslog-ng:                                        [FAILED]
Plugin module not found in 'module-path'; module-path='/lib64/syslog-ng', module='afsql'
Error parsing main, syntax error, unexpected LL_IDENTIFIER, expecting $end in /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf at line X, column Y:

local1.info /var/log/programname.log
^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my syslog-ng.conf file I removed the following line:

```
local1.info /var/log/program1.log
```

and replaced it with this:

```
destination d_log1 {file("/var/log/program1.log"); };
log { source(s_sys); filter(f_local1); destination(d_log1); };
filter f_local1   { facility(local1); };
```

NOTE- I have also defined the source s_sys in my syslog-ng.conf file:

```
source s_sys {
        file ("/proc/kmsg" program_override("kernel: "));
        unix-dgram ("/dev/log");
        internal();
        udp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(514));
};
```